# Как можно связать программу и ssh?

Tags: ssh

C клиента нужен доступ к серверу через ssh, есть ли dll, которая облегчит это дело? Или код для создания нужного сертификата для ssh?
Пробовал напролом через сокеты достучаться на 22 порт, сервер отрубил коннект

Comment: опишите задачу детальнее. Что именно и как делаете. Пока вижу только то, что пытаетесь достучатся с винды.

Comment: Есть ли способ подключится через ssh к серваку из программы? Или вас интересует подключение через сокеты? Но без сертивикатов или чего-то там, сервак отрубает коннект. Что, в принципе, логично

Comment: подключиться с своей программы можно, но это дело такое. Для начала можно посмотреть на http://www.putty.org/ - там с исходниками. Но если нужно скачать файл/запустить команду удаленно, то проще использовать тот же putty, но дергая его напрямую. Сертификаты будут нужны, но тот же путти их умеет генерировать.